# I cannot compile Z3 using Visual C++ & gcc

Tags: visual-c++, gcc, z3

I'm starter Z3 so my question may be too basic.
But If you let me know some information for my question, I'm very happy.
I searched before history in this site.
But I couldn't get detailed information for me. ( because maybe..my question is too basic..)

1. [using Visual C++]
   1) First of all, I downloaded "z3 4.3.0 for window" at codePlex site.
    But this file doesn't have example file(test_capi.c).
    So I got "z3-89c1785b73225a1b363c0e485f854613121b70a7.zip" for example file.
     ( I cannot remember what I can get... :( )

   I succeeded compiling python file as codeplex site quide.
    But I cannot compile test_capi.c using Visual C++.
    I also added "test_capi.c" at "z3 4.3.0 for window" folder but I cannot also compile.

   Lastly, I just tried using "test_capi.vcxproj" of "z3-src-4.1.1" and this is succeeded.
    I cannot understand.

   If i want to test "my file", what file is needed at "z3 4.3.0 for window"?
     Or
    Do I have to use only "z3 4.1.1" for visual c++ and add "my file" at some location of "z3 4.1.1"? ( All files of Z3 4.1.1 is needed?? AND what is the Some location?)

   I read other some comment - "Z3 4.3.0" is simplified.
    I understood this comment that I can use only "z3 4.3.0" and test successfully.
    But as i told you, I cannot compile.
    Please give me some information..
2. [using gcc in ubuntu]
   First of all, I downloaded "z3-4.3.2.07d56bdc705c-x86-ubuntu-12.04.zip" from codeplex site.
   Because I tried git command for getting source code but i cannot find source code.
   ( I also don't know the reason..)
   Anyway... "z3-4.3.2.07d56bdc705c-x86-ubuntu-12.04.zip" doesn't have any example file and only bin & include folder is existed.
   So I also used "z3 4.1.1" but i cannot compile using below command.
   gcc -fopenmp -o test_capi -I ../../Include -L ../../lib test_capi.c -lz3-gmp

   Error is "cannot find -lz3-gmp."

   In some comment, I found "use "sudo install"" but i don't know how i can install lz3.
   (Of course only "sudo install" doesn't work and "sudo apt-get install z3" also doesn't work...)

   For compiling "test_capi.c" using gcc, could you explain in detail..?

   I'm confused many kinds of guide but i couldn't get basic information for me.

   Thank you in advance and I hope to get information...even if my question is too basic..

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use only one version of the source code. Version 4.1.1 is very old and newer versions do not come with test_capi.vcxproj anymore, instead everything is done via the Makefile. For the very latest version please use the `unstable` branch (e.g., by selecting `unstable` [here](http://z3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest) and then clicking download.)

The examples can be compiled by calling `nmake examples` (on Windows) or `make examples` (on Linux) in the `build` directory. The makefile has a target called _ex_c_example which shows how to call the compiler for the C example. The various variables that this target uses are defined in build/config.mk. Note that these variables are set to different values on Windows and Linux (this file is produced by `python scripts/mk_make.py`).

The git command on many Linux distributions is not compatible with the codeplex git server (for a fix see [here](http://z3.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Git%20HTTPS%20cloning%20errors)), but of course this is not necessary if you download the source code from the webpage directly.

Comment: I got information about 4.1.1 version from your comment.
I downloaded "latest source code" and "bin&include for window".
And then as you told you, I used "python scripts/mk_make.py" for using nmake command.
But as i written before, this was just compiled only python example file.
I already succeeded compiling python file. First of all, I want to compile c example file. For this, What should I do? And then, I want to compile my c file(not example file).
For this, What should I do,too? Lastly, I want to compile AVR source code. AVR source code have AVR header files from AVR compiler.

Comment: Running python scripts/mk_make.py only creates the build directory, the configuration and the Makefiles, it doesn't compile anything. After that, you need to go into the build directory and run nmake, which should compile libz3.dll and z3.exe. Running "nmake examples" should build test_capi.exe. Does that work for you?

Comment: Thank you for your kind response. I tried "nmake examples" on the visual studio prompt but "fatal error C1083. omp.h : no such file or directory" was happened.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio Express? This version of visual studio does not have support for OpenMP. If it's impossible for you to use a different version of Visual Studio, you can disable parallelism support in Z3 by editing build/config.mk and removing all references to /openmp and adding -D_NO_OMP_ instead.

Comment: I Finally succeeded by your help!! So I'm so grateful to you. I have another questions. First, I want to check SW Quality using SMT solver. For example buffer overflow and etc, in c/cpp files. When i use nmake command, just c/cpp files was built. If you inform some guide or documents, I'll find my way.. AND second, If i check SW quality of AVR code, AVR application source code should use AVR header files of other path. So When I used CBMC, I added "-I ../../../usr/lib/avr " path in CBMC command. In Z3, if i want to this, Should I modify make files? Thank you again and again.

Comment: I think verification function is "Z3_check_and_get_model()". right? If  it is right, I'll study source code related with "Z3_check_and_get_model()". And I still wonder before my second question. (AND second, If i check SW quality of AVR code, AVR application source code should use AVR header files of other path. So When I used CBMC, I added "-I ../../../usr/lib/avr " path in CBMC command. In Z3, if i want to this, Should I modify make files?) Thank you again and again.

Comment: It seems my second question is little strange.. I think although AVR source is c base code this cannot be compiled. Right? And i think if i want to use AVR source code I have to change from AVR source code(c base) to Z3. Right? Of course, Z3 just can be used for some theories, so it seems that it is difficult to verifying AVR source code. How about your opinion? (I wanted to just verifying AVR UART source code..) Thank you very much. ( I'm really grateful to you. )

Comment: Z3 is an SMT solver, that is it tries to decide logical formulas, usually provided in SMT2 language or via the API. While it is used in many verification tools, it does not verify C programs itself. For example, CBMC has a backend for Z3 that can be used instead of a SAT solver. See also Leo's answer to a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13982937/converting-ir-to-z3-formula